# Is there any reason why one candidate only runs for election once?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

When running for an office such as the presidency for the USA, one candidate will never run for the office more than once.

Why?

Comment: What do you mean? Candidates can run multiple times and they do, for reelection or when they didn't win the first time.

Comment: Run in which race?  Did you not Watch Animaniacs:  "John Quincy Adams is number Six/ and it's Andrew Jackson's butt he kicks/ But Jackson learned to play politics/ Next time he's the one that the country picks".  In the 2016 election both Trump and Hilary had previously had a failed bid for office a piece (Trump ran for the Reform Party and Hilary was in 2008 primary but lost to Obama).  Current Candidate Joe Biden is making his Third Primary Bid (the previous two in 1988, and 2008, and currently 2020).

Comment: @hszmv - Does launching an exploratory committee and maybe implying that you are thinking of running but not announcing one's self as a candidate really count as a 'failed bid'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most candidates did run multiple times, though running as a party's candidate more than once without winning is rare in modern times and somewhat common historically. Many presidential candidates don't win their primary on their first try, Reagan and H. W. Bush both won the presidency after losing in the primary. Nixon is the most recent President to have lost the election and later won, and then there is Grover Cleveland who served two non sequential terms. Many candidates lost multiple presidential elections without ever winning, but this hasn't happened since changes to the primary system in the 1970s. Previously the party's leaders at the national convention had much more sway over who was chosen and they tended to stick more with someone they knew, but in modern elections winning individual states primary/caucus, is the main path to nomination.

Modern candidates don't run multiple times in a presidential election, because it's much harder to convince the masses that it's worth running a losing candidate, especially against an incumbent that already beat them. Furthermore, the election process is grueling, and lasts about 2 years for campaigning and another 6 months to a year of pre-planning that losing candidates have been unwilling to commit to for a second time.